# Error uploading ResearchKit app to App Store - ERROR ITMS-90035 Invalid signature

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, researchkit

I have created an iOS app that uses the ResearchKit framework.  I have dragged ResearchKit.xcodeproj to my app project and embedded ResearchKit.framework in my app target, with the option embed & sign. I am using ResearchKit 2.0.0 and Xcode 11.3.1.

When I try to upload the archive (release) to the App Store I get the error "ERROR ITMS-90035.  Invalid signature.  Code is not signed at all.  The file at path [XXX.app/Frameworks/ResearchKit.framework/plist-to-strings.py] is not properly signed."  This file is part of Apple's ResearchKit, and the settings under "Signing and Capabilities" do not allow me to add a signing certificate - I select Distribution certificate but Xcode leaves the selection as None.

My app has my distribution certificate and provisioning file, and I have followed the suggestions in the error message with regards to selecting "Clean Build Folder" and deleting the build folder from Finder.

Has anyone had a similar problem and been able to upload to the App store?

Comment: Hey @nickycw I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Have to tried to add the Researchkit via Pods?